# Fetching the id from the first column of GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid in which I am showing some records in each row. Here's how it is:
[image]

Now, my problem is that when I press the view button, I want to fetch the ID from the first column in a session variable so that I can display the same ID on the next page.

For the ItemTemplate of EditButton, I am using this code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="EditBtn" CssClass="btn green" CommandName="edit" ToolTip="Edit" Text="Edit" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: On what value is the AutoGenerateColumn property set? How does your datasource look like?

Comment: The ID's in the first column are not auto-genrated but are fetched from the database. So, in they can be in random not necessarily in the order I wrote above. Here's the link to the code of the GirdView HTML source. http://pastebin.com/2Zj2DhJU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try passing it as command argument:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton 
        ID="EditBtn" 
        CssClass="btn green" 
        CommandName="edit" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FirstColumnId") %>'
        OnCommand="EditCommand"
        ToolTip="Edit" 
        Text="Edit" 
        runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

and in the code behind:

```
protected void EditCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var id = e.CommandArgument;
    // TODO: do something with the id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. No changes are required at your aspx

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserID"] = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lb1")).Text.Trim();
}
```

Other method (Using DataKeyNames - Preferred)

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserID"] = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```